# Get all post from table and put it in excel sheet

Tags: wordpress

I have website with 25025 posts, And i need to get the post name and the post url for all post in 2014. and export it in Excel sheet.

How can i do that.

i try to do this query but i dont get the URL of post and get all post in 2014

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
        FROM $table 
        WHERE YEAR(post_date) = '2014' 
        "
        , OBJECT 
);
```

you will be returned a $results object with rows of data. (var_dump($results) to see what you have)